# Trying to render value of input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to work with a input value present in the source code only when the user has tried to login once (and entered a wrong password).

The scenario is as follows:

First attempt before login, part of the code looks like this:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="user_email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="text-field form-control" html="{:spellcheck=&gt;&quot;false&quot;}" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

After a second attempt happens, the email address that was used it's rendered in value:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="user_email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input class="text-field form-control" html="{:spellcheck=&gt;&quot;false&quot;}" id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" value="heregoestheemail@gmail.com" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can I render that email address if the user is not logged in yet? I know that once logged I'd do something like <%= current_user.email %> but there is way to get that value attribute?

Answer (score 0):

you should work with form_for

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% f.text_field :email (not sure f.email_field works)
<%= end %>
```

be sure @user is define in controller (@user = User.new or @user is come back from controller with errors => show @user.errors and contain precedent values)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html